# How to change the default TTL of TCP/IP packets?

Tags: command-line, networking, ip, router

I need to change the default TTL of TCP/IP packets sent from my Ubuntu computer. I found the solution for Windows:

1. To make reg-file:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\servic es\Tcpip\Parameters]
   "DefaultTTL"=dword:00000081
   ```
2. To execute this commands in console:

   ```
   netsh int ipv4 set glob defaultcurhoplimit=129
   netsh int ipv6 set glob defaultcurhoplimit=129
   ```

The question is how should I translate this solution for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To change the default [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) of TCP/IP packets sent from your Linux computer you can run the following command:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl=129
```

Or:

```
echo 129 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_default_ttl
```

Or:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo 129 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_default_ttl'
```

But you have to run one of those commands whenever the computer boots. To make this setting persistent across reboots you could append the following line to the file `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl=129
```

You should do the same with `ipv6` instead of `ipv4` if you want to change the settings for ipv6 as well.

Comment: I used nano to edit /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_default_ttl and now I can't see any of my wifi networks

Comment: Not true for ipv6; in ipv6 they don't call it `ttl` anymore. The correct variable name for sysctl is `net.ipv6.conf.default.hop_limit`.

Comment: ⁺¹, increasing the default 64 to 65 works as a workaround against annoying mobile ISPs in our country that limit internet traffic upon detecting it being shared from the phone.

Answer (score 5):

**for IPv6**:

The other answer here says, "You should do the same with ipv6" but this does not work. IPv6 uses `net.ipv6.conf.all.hop_limit` and `net.ipv6.conf.default.hop_limit`. However, these values are overwritten by interface-specific names such as `net.ipv6.conf.eth0.hop_limit`. To change them all, use:

```
for N in $(sudo sysctl --all 2>/dev/null |grep -Eo "^net\.ipv6\.conf\.[^\.]+\.hop_limit"); do
    sudo sysctl --write "$N=128"
done
```

where `128` is the desired new value.

To make this permanent (survive reboot) for IPv4 *and* IPv6:

```
sudo sysctl --all 2>/dev/null |grep -E -e "^net\.ipv6\.conf\.[^\.]+\.hop_limit" -e "net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl" |sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/11-custom-ttl-hop.conf
```