# Internet Connection for Ubuntu VM in virtualbox on corporate laptop

Tags: virtualbox

I am working on a project on my corportate laptop (has significant security measures and I do not yet have admin rights) where I have installed a Ubuntu 16.04.2 desktop in Virtual box. I cannot get internet connectivity in the VM. I have tried all network configurations available, and obviously started with the NAT option, which from my reading is the easiest to configure.

I came across these suggestion: · Internet Access in Ubuntu on VirtualBox

As the NAT setting did not work (as suggested by top rated answer in the link), I wanted to try the second answer. This suggests I go to the network property settings and allow other users to connect. However, I cannot try this out as I do not yet have admin rights on my corporate laptop (I have applied for it).

Any other suggestions on how I can get the internet connection in the VM working? I have tried all the possibilities in the network section of the virtual box manager.

Also, once I get admin rights I will likely try the second-voted method in the above link. Do you believe this is a valid/appropriate procedure?

Thank you

Comment: Similar questions have been asked and answered, however, I believe security issues on corporate laptop may be an issue.

Comment: If you're using NAT without success, you may be subject of TTL detection, so change the default [TTL value](https://askubuntu.com/a/670276/260379) for tcp packets to match the your host + 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you set the Ubuntu Guest OS VirtualBox network settings to use `Bridged Adapter`.

If that doesn't fix it for you, talk to your network administrator or system administrator.

Comment: Turns out it was the corporate VPN blocking me out. After this I was able to use just NAT and it worked.